# Sanselan vs Java-Image-io

Tags: java, image-processing, jai

Which better of these two libraries `Sanselan` or `Java Advanced Imaging API`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sanselan has some features that JAI does not, like support for reading and writing EXIF data.

However, if the features you need are present in both, I'd go with JAI, because it has much better documentation.